# Gerund or noun after "for"?

Tags: difference, verbs

I wrote:

> Image processing techniques have been widely used **for detecting defects** in industrial equipment.

Maybe I could write it as:

> Image processing techniques have been widely used for **the detection of defects** in industrial equipment.

In many case, I have seen a gerund is used after "for". I would like to know is it a rule or a noun form of a verb like "detection" is also can be used? is there any difference?

Comment: Same meaning in both, but don't call "detecting" a gerund; it is a verb with its own direct object. So the question really is "subordinate clause or noun phrase as complement of "for"?

Comment: @BillJ I thought "detecting defects" is a gerund phrase.

Comment: @Cardinal In trad grammar, yes, but in modern grammar we'd call "detecting defects in industrial equipment" a non-finite subordinate clause, or more specifically a 'gerund-participial clause'.

Comment: @BillJ I'm really impressed by the modern grammar. I should start learning modern grammar sooner or later. Thanks.

Comment: are used to detect defects....  why even go down that prolix path?  *used for the detection of defects

Comment: Aside: as BillJ points out, they impart the same meaning. When given the choice between similar constructions, I tend to take the shorter. Although in this instance, the difference is not consequential. To my eyes, the first one flows better.

Comment: In answer to your question, @Ahmad - there is no rule governing this usage. It's up to you to decide which one sounds better. Remember: language is originally a _spoken_ medium, not a written one! Rhythm and musicality are as important in English as they are in any language.